# Why my meta boxes won't show in front post page?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, posts, meta-boxes

I see it everywhere: in single post, in category archives etc, but in front page post not.

I display the metaboxes in this way:

```
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'test_1', true) != '' ) { ?><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'test_1', true);?><?php } ?>
```

What's wrong?
What i'm doing wrong?
Is possible to display the meta boxies in a different way?

**Here is the code:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_xy_taxonomies', 0 );
function create_pc_db_taxonomies() {
register_taxonomy( 'genre', 'post', array( 'hierarchical' => false, 'label' => __('Tests', 'series'), 'query_var' => 'test', 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tests' ) ) );

$prefix = 'xy_meta_';


$meta_box = array(
    'id' => 'xy-meta-box',
    'title' => 'Xy tests',
    'page' => 'post',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Test_1',
            'id' => 'test_1',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Test_2',
            'id' => 'test_2',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array('','1'),
            'std' => ''
        ),
    )
);

add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_box');

function mytheme_add_box() {
    global $meta_box;

    add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], 'mytheme_show_box', $meta_box['page'], $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority']);
}

function mytheme_show_box() {
    global $meta_box, $post;


    echo '<input type="hidden" name="mytheme_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';

    echo '<table class="form-table">';

    foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {

        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

        echo '<tr>',
                '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
                '<td>';
        switch ($field['type']) {
            case 'text':
                echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />',
                    '<br />', $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'textarea':
                echo '<textarea name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="4" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea>',
                    '<br />', $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'select':
                echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<option', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
                break;
            case 'radio':
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option['name'];
                }
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
                break;
        }
        echo    '<td>',
            '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'mytheme_save_data');


function mytheme_save_data($post_id) {
    global $meta_box;
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['mytheme_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Multipost: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74176/why-my-meta-boxes-wont-show-in-front-post-page

Answer (score 0):

Your test would only display the content of the custom field key test_1, yeah?